# Android Keyboard resolution

Tags: java, android, keyboard

I'm working on an android soft keyboard. It seems I keep making my canvas about 533x320 resolution even though my phone (galaxy) is 800x480.

I've even tried making onMeasure in my view call setMeasure with 800x480 with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />

</manifest>
```

My reference is [this link.](http://code.google.com/p/softkeyboard/source/browse/branches/theme-support/project/?r=1142)